# Deny all external HTTPs request to Cloud Run app except for specific IPs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, serverless, firewall, google-cloud-run, vpc

I recently migrated my app from cloud AppEngine to Cloud Run. in App engine I used it simple firewall rules configuration to have to rules
1- deny all ingress IPs
2- allow only 2 specific IPs

I created a Serverless connector and linked it to the default VPC network where I added a new firewall to deny all IPV4 requests but still requests are passing through.

Comment: How about if you check the rule order in your firewall. 
Another alternative is denying IPs in your CORS configuration (assuming that you have one)

Comment: Use ingress settings to limit the service visibility: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/ingress#command-line